# Calculate Decile with condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking to create a 'decile' column based on client attributes (type of account). I can get a decile for the entire dataset using `qcut` function:

```
df['Decile_rank'] = pd.qcut(df['bps_impact'], 10, labels = False)
```

But I cannot add the filter by client attribute.

How to filter so that the column `Decile_rank` would be dependent of the client attribute column. I'm new to this space and would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: Have you tried to use `groupby` to create groups by client attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Simple case of `groupby()` `apply()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"client":np.repeat(["A","B","C"],10),"val":np.random.randint(10,100,30)})

df["quantile"] = df.groupby("client", as_index=False).apply(lambda dfa: pd.qcut(dfa.val, q=10, labels=False)).values
```